# Hoe Do You Calculate 3-D Model Angles (Game Development)

Tags: 3d, angle

```
box1.origin = box2.origin                
box1.angles = (0,90,0);                      
box2.angles = (0,45,0);                
box2 linkTo(box1);                  
box1.angles = (20,90,0);                     
print(box2.angles) = (13.9954, 43.2192, -14.4328)
```

So I have a rectangular box (box1) that has an angle of (0,90,0)...(pitch,yaw,roll)
and I place another box (box2) at the same origin with an angle of (0,45,0). So both the boxes are colliding with each other since they are at the same origin. I then link box2 (0,45,0) with box1 (0,90,0) and then rotate box1 to an angle of (20,90,0). Since box2 is linked, it acts as if both boxes are one model. Now, if I print box2's new angle, it is (13.9954, 43.2192, -14.4328). So how can I calculate that angle mathematically given box1 has an initial angle of (20,90,0)? Because I'm wanting to place box2 at the same origin but with a 45 degree difference.

The above problem is just an example of what I am looking for, which is, how can you mathematically rotate 3-D objects (models) perpendicular to a particular vector plane. Thus, if I successfully had this working and I placed a model at any angle and started rotating on any vector axis (right,up,forward), it would create a circular disk shape relative to the vector direction.

If anyone needs additional information of maybe some pictures to help clarify the problem, let me know. Thanks!